# How to change class when it scroll to end of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok i have 3 divs. I have fixed menu in second div and i want that fixed menu is only fixed in that second menu and when it come out of that div it is `display:none;` This is my fiddle. Any suggestion?

https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1817/

```
if ($(this).scrollTop()>=$('.compare-wrapper').position().top)
    $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','block');
else
    $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside scroll event:

```
$(document).on( 'scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('.compare-wrapper').position().top)
        $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','block');
    else
         $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','none');
});
```

[<kbd>**Check Demo Here**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/Luthando/wx38rz5L/1818/)

Comment: In your demo disapear when it comes to compare-menu ... i want to be visible only in that div

Comment: I updated my answer and demo....you might want to hide that div by default, so that it appears only when it is inside...check the demo